# Invert XYZ Euler Rotation Value

Tags: python

I [nabbed some code](https://github.com/patmo141/object_bounding_box) that creates `created_box` object that represents the [Arbitrarily oriented minimum bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) by volume of the `selected_object`

I get the rotation of the created box like so:

```
rotX = created_box.rotation_euler[0]
rotY = created_box.rotation_euler[1]
rotZ = created_box.rotation_euler[2]
```

I want to apply that rotation in reverse to `selected_object` such that the minimum bounding box is axis-aligned. I think to do this, I need to pass a ZYX euler instead of an XYZ. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you checked the [Blender API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_mode)?

Answer (score 2):

I set my selected object's `rotation_mode` to `ZYX` and entered the values as:

```
selected_object.rotation_mode = 'ZYX'
selected_object.rotation_euler[0] = rotX * -1
selected_object.rotation_euler[1] = rotY * -1
selected_object.rotation_euler[2] = rotZ * -1
```

This rotated the object into the correct position.